# Using QXmlStreamReader to read configuration file of key-value pairs

Tags: c++, c++14, xml, stream, qt

#### Background

The following XML snippet contains configuration parameters for our application in key-value pair manner. (Despite using [INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) for such purpose may be better, I have to use XML files.)

```xml
<configuration>
    <parameter id="serial_port_name">ttyS0</parameter>
    <parameter id="serial_port_baud_rate">9600</parameter>
    <parameter id="check_period">1000</parameter>
    <parameter id="locale">hu_HU</parameter>
    <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

I would like to read the configuration parameters and store them inside a [`QHash<QString, QString>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html) object with minimal overhead, therefore I've chosen the [`QXmlStreamReader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html) for iterating through XML elements.

#### Current code

The `toConfigurationMap()` method of the following `class` iterates through the elements of XML file and when a `<configuration>` element is found, starts another iteration on the level of `<parameter>` elements to parse them.

```
class ConfigurationReader {
public:
    explicit ConfigurationReader(QFile& input) : reader(&input) {
    }

    QHash<QString, QString> toConfigurationMap() {
        QHash<QString, QString> output;

        for(auto token = reader.tokenType(); !reader.atEnd();
                token = reader.readNext()) {
            if(token != QXmlStreamReader::StartElement ||
                    reader.name() != "configuration")
                continue;

            while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                if(reader.name() == "parameter") {
                    QString id = reader.attributes().value("id").toString();
                    output.insert(id, reader.readElementText());
                }
                else {
                    reader.skipCurrentElement();
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

private:
    QXmlStreamReader reader;
};
```

#### Goals

I would like to reduce the complexity of the code above, by somehow take apart the nested loops. In order to the `toConfigurationMap()` method be more cleaner, I would like to communicate to the reader that *"it parses the parameters for each configuration elements"* through the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Case for not using a `class`

It's not clear to me whether you need a class for what you are doing. Unless you need to be able to construct an instance of `ConfigurationReader` and pass it around, I would say get rid of the class. You can have a function with the simple interface

```
QHash<QString, QString> getConfigurationMap(QFile& input);
```

I would further suggest putting the function in a `namespace` that is specific to your app.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   QHash<QString, QString> getConfigurationMap(QFile& input);
}
```

#### Use smaller functions

Instead of one large function, divide the code into multiple functions. Think of *what* you are doing rather than *how* you are doing it. The *what*s usually translate to smaller functions and *how*s translate to loops, conditionals, branches, etc.

Given that, `getConfigurationMap` can be implemented as:

```
namespace MyApp
{
   // Implementation detail.
   void getConfigurationMap(QXmlStreamReader& reader,
                            QHash<QString, QString>& map);

   // User facing interface.
   QHash<QString, QString> getConfigurationMap(QFile& input)
   {
      QXmlStreamReader reader(input);
      QHash<QString, QString> map;
      getConfigurationMap(reader, map);
      return map;
   }
}
```

The second overload (the one that's listed first) can be implemented as:

```
namespace MyApp
{
   void skipUntilConfiguration(QXmlStreamReader& reader);

   void readParamters(QXmlStreamReader& reader,
                      QHash<QString, QString>& map);

   // Implementation detail.
   void getConfigurationMap(QXmlStreamReader& reader,
                            QHash<QString, QString>& map);
   {
      skipUntilConfiguration(reader);
      readParamters(reader, map):
   }

   // User facing interface.
   QHash<QString, QString> getConfigurationMap(QFile& input)
   {
      QXmlStreamReader reader(input);
      QHash<QString, QString> map;
      getConfigurationMap(reader, map);
      return map;
   }
}
```

The code can be wrapped up by implementing the final two helper functions.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   void skipUntilConfiguration(QXmlStreamReader& reader)
   {
      whiile ( !reader.atEnd() )
      {
         if ( reader.tokenType() == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement &&
              reader.name() == "configuration" )
         {
            return;
         }
      }
   }

   void readParamters(QXmlStreamReader& reader,
                      QHash<QString, QString>& map)
   {
      while ( reader.readNextStartElement() ) {
          if ( reader.name() == "parameter" ) {
              QString id = reader.attributes().value("id").toString();
              map.insert(id, reader.readElementText());
          }
          else {
              reader.skipCurrentElement();
          }
      }
   }

   void getConfigurationMap(QXmlStreamReader& reader,
                            QHash<QString, QString>& map)
   {
      skipUntilConfiguration(reader);
      readParamters(reader, map):
   }

   QHash<QString, QString> getConfigurationMap(QFile& input)
   {
      QXmlStreamReader reader(input);
      QHash<QString, QString> map;
      getConfigurationMap(reader, map);
      return map;
   }
}
```

The above code assumes that there is only one "configuration" element in your XML file. If that assumption is not correct, the functions need to be tweaked a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks to be about the expected level of complexity for the task.  I wouldn't attempt to reduce it any further - you're unlikely to make it faster, and definitely likely to hinder its clarity.

The nested loop structure accurately reflects the data's structure, and I think there's a lot of value in keeping the two aligned.

The thing I might actually question is the *interface* exposed by this class.  It would be very useful to present a `QSettings` facade to your configuration file to make it easier to interface with other code.  You're not far from being able to do that, but `QSettings::registerFormat()` wants its reader to have this signature:

> ```
> bool myReadFunc(QIODevice &device, QSettings::SettingsMap &map);
> ```

The `input` parameter can just as easily be a `QIODevice&` as a `QFile&`, given that we only create a reader from it, and it wouldn't be hard to use a `QSettings::SettingsMap` (which is just an alias of `QMap<QString,QVariant>`) in place of `output`.

Comment: Using `QSettings` is a wise idea. Thank you for reminding me to that.